# Ubuntu 23.10 bold font in panel

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I have been trying to get the top panel to show bold fonts (e.g., for the date/clock and battery percentage) without success. I tried `font-weight: bold`, `font-weight: 500` for `#panel`, `#panel *`, etc. in the shell css. Other things, such as `font-family` and `font-variant: italic` work as expected.

I have also tried themes that advertise bold fonts in the panel (e.g., https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1305272) with no luck.

This is pretty vanilla install of Ubuntu 23.10 with an X.org session (although the same seems to happen under Wayland).

The first question is whether anybody else is experiencing this. If so, are there any ideas how to make it work?